# Show filename only in upload field

Tags: javascript, django

I'm trying to show filename only in my upload filefield. Is my idea correct? For some reason it doesn't work. The method works but I still get full path in the field. Keep in mind I have addFileField() which gives more filefields if a user wants.

script.js

```
var ufile = 1;
var currentE = null;

function addFileFild(){
    ufile = ufile+1;
    $("#addFileFild").before('<p><input type="file" name="ufile'+ufile+'" size="20"></p>');
    return 0;
}

function showSrc() {
   document.getElementById("myframe").href = document.getElementById("ufile").value;
   var theexa=document.getElementById("myframe").href.replace("file:///","");
   alert(document.getElementById("myframe").href.replace("file:///",""));
}
```

upload.html

```
<div class="block upload">
<h2>{% trans "Lähetä tiedostoja" %}</h2>
   <div class="content">
     <form id="uploadForm" action="{% url fileman.views.upload %}" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
<p><input type="file" name="ufile1" onChange="showSrc();" size="20"><a href="#" id="myframe"></a></p>
<p id="addFileFild"><a href="#" id="myframe" onclick="return addFileFild();"><img src="{{ fileman_media_url }}/plus_icon.png"WIDTH=25 HEIGHT=25></a></p>
<p><input type="hidden" name="path" value="{{ pwd }}">
<input type="submit" onclick="TINYPOP.show('Lähetetään! Ole hyvä odota. Tämä ikkuna sulkeutuu kun lähetys on valmistunut...',{sticky: true, position: 'top-left'});" value="Lähetä!"/></p>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: "The method works but I still get full path in the field" What field? You talking about the `<input type='file' />`? You can not control that value.

Comment: So I can't get the filename only instead of the path in the upload field? Like google chrome does it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not control what is displayed in the file input element. Modern Day browsers limit it to just the file name while older browser show the whole path.

Comment: What about printing it right under the filefield then? Is that possible? Ok I got the alert working by giving an id to the input type field and using that in showSrc() document.getElementById("ufile").value; . Still shows the full path but I think I can work from here to develop somekind of list of files somewhere on the page.

Comment: Get the value and rip off the path: something like `filePath.value.split("\\").pop();`

Comment: Simplest way is to get rid of the unecessary path as epascarello suggested. That's why I do on my projects.